# How to set the Style property of a ListBox control in code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a part of Xaml code that I want to write in C# code.
Code:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

I tried:

```
listBox.ItemContainerStyle = new Style();

Setter setter = new Setter();
setter.Property = ....??
setter.Value = true;

listBox.ItemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
```

But cant find the Focusable property to insert in setter. Can anyone help?

Comment: Isn't that just UIElement.FocusableProperty ?

Comment: Yea thanks verry much. i forgot to use ListBoxItem and not just ListBox.. setter.Property = ListBoxItem.FocusableProperty ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work just fine.

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.FocusableProperty, false));

listBox.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a clean and simple way of doing it right !

Answer (score 2):

```
setter.Property = ListBoxItem.FocusVisualStyleProperty;
```

This [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ddb7fd77-dea1-40f5-a5b7-30d35ecda70e/creating-a-control-template-with-code-behind?forum=wpf) can help you. It talks about creating templates in code behind.

Comment: Please refrain from giving link-only answers. Try to copy and paste the relevant part of the linked page in your answer, as it cannot be ensured that this page will still exist in the future.